# Scrapy returns results correctly to terminal but only writes first result to .CSV

Tags: python, scrapy, export-to-csv

This spider crawls concatenated links formed by adding a unique product ID from a csv file to a URL and scraping the data form the given page.

While using the -O command to write the results to .CSV, only the first result is written.

All of the items are selected and looped correctly and the correct results are shown in the output in the terminal, but only the first item is written to CSV.

Are you not able to use if else in a loop like this?
Do I need another for x in response.xpath when defining the yield?

There is no mistake with the write path and output file

I tried several variations and creating a for try except for each element yielded but the results are the same

Please let me know if you have any advice to resolve this, thank you

```
import scrapy
import pandas as pd


def readcsv():
    df = pd.read_csv('tsuji2.csv')
    #return df.values
    return df['URL'].values.tolist()


class TsujijsonSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'tsujijson22'
    start_urls = ['https://www.example.co.jp/store/online/']


def parse(self, response):
    for URL in readcsv():



        base_url = 'https://www.example.co.jp/store/online/p/{}'
        yield scrapy.Request(base_url.format(URL), callback=self.data)


def data(self, response):

        try:
            if response.xpath(u"//span[contains(text(), '〇')]").get():
                yield{
                'zaiko green' : response.css('span.green::text').get()}

            elif response.xpath(u"//span[contains(text(), '△')]").get():
                yield{
                    'zaiko red': response.css('span.red:nth-of-type(1)::text').get()}

            else: yield {
                'zaiko red2': response.css('span.upperRight::text').get()}



        except:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All results must have the same column header name to write to CSV correctly it seems

```
def data(self, response):
        try:
            if response.xpath(u"//span[contains(text(), '〇')]").get():
                yield{
                'zaiko' : response.css('span.green::text').get()}

            elif response.xpath(u"//span[contains(text(), '△')]").get():
                yield{
                    'zaiko': response.css('span.red:nth-of-type(1)::text').get()}

            else: yield {
                'zaiko': response.css('span.upperRight::text').get()}

        except:
            pass
```

Will yield correct results in one column

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have to type **-t csv** at the end of the command, like:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -o my_csv_file.csv -t csv
```

Also, I don't know if it works for you, but I usually write my results in a [json line](https://jsonlines.org/) file - each row represents a json.

I type this on terminal:

```
scrapy crawl my_spider -o my_json_line_file.jl
```

One thing that is important is to be at the folder your spider is in. For example, before run the command I wrote above, I type:

```
cd my_project_folder/my_project_folder/spiders
```

I hope I helped you! :)

## UPDATE

I tried to run almost the same code (only changing URLs list origin) and it works. Here is the code I am using:

```
import scrapy

class MatsukiyoSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'matsukiyo'
    start_urls = ['https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/store/online/']

    def parse(self, response):
        for URL in ["4582352470220", "4901061475737", "4901061475942"]:
            base_url = 'https://www.matsukiyo.co.jp/store/online/p/{}'
            yield scrapy.Request(base_url.format(URL), callback=self.data)

    def data(self, response):
            try:
                if response.xpath(u"//span[contains(text(), '〇')]").get():
                    yield{
                    'zaiko green' : response.css('span.green::text').get()}

                elif response.xpath(u"//span[contains(text(), '△')]").get():
                    yield{
                        'zaiko red': response.css('span.red:nth-of-type(1)::text').get()}

                else: yield {
                    'zaiko red2': response.css('span.upperRight::text').get()}

            except:
                pass
```

And here is my CSV file:

[CSV result with only 3 URLs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cwqbo.png)

PS: I typed the following on terminal:

> scrapy crawl matsukiyo -s LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG -o mats.csv -t csv

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but the issue remains, and unfortunately I need the file to be output as CSV

Comment: Have you tried to open you CSV with tab separator? I tried the same code here in my machine (only using 3 URLs) and it works :( - I updated my answer with the code I used).

Comment: Thank you for the update, it is really appreciated that you are still assisting me with this, however the issue arises when there is more than one result, for example your code works great as all the results are 〇 if you use different product pages that contain △ or neither of these 2 characters, only the first and subsequent values are recorded. 

In your result, all items are 〇 and recorded correctly, if it goes 〇 -> △ -> △ -> none 〇 only the first 〇 will be recorded (even though the rest show correctly in the terminal

After testing, I have realized the issue, I will post again below.

Comment: The issue is that you cannot use several different column headers
'zaiko green' 
'zaiko red'
'zaiko red2'
Are causing the issue, it will find any results that = the first result, in this case 'zaiko green' 
Then scrapy finds the next result,  and needs to write to 'zaiko red' but the column header is already populated with 'zaiko green'  and thus returns null (a blank row is entered)
To circumvent this all column headers must be the same it seems, maybe this is a quirk of Scrapy or that you have to define a new column somehow.

Comment: Marina Rocha Guimarães, thank you for the help having someone to go over the code with and look at it from a different light helped solve the issue, I hope you can help more people on this site from here on